# Sample weights in multilevel APC models

Tags: mixed-model, stata, multilevel-analysis, weights

I am conducting a age-period-cohort analysis using repeated cross-sectional survey data and a multilevel model approach in Stata, where cohort (birth year) and period (survey year) are modeled as cross-classified random effects. As such, all my data is taken from the same data source (27 waves of the General Social Survey) and the source only provides one sample weight (wtssall) that covers all the waves. My question is: how do I deal with the sample weights in this case?

As I understand it from the Stata manual (http://www.stata.com/bookstore/pdf/xt_xtmixed.pdf), weights should be included at both level 1 and level 2 while using weight rescaling of some sort, but when I try to implement this I run into problems:

```
.mixed homosex age [pw = wtssall] || _all: R.cohort || year:, pweight(wtssall) pwscale(size)

*weights not constant within groups defined by year*
```

Including the sample weight at level 1 only gives this error message:

```
. mixed homosex age [pw = wtssall]  || _all: R.cohort || year:

 *robust variances and pweights not supported when highest-level group 
 encompasses all the data*
```

Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Regards,

David Ekstam

PhD candidate, Department of Government

Uppsala University, Sweden